# How to pass current id in fancybox jquery as a parameter

Tags: jquery

```
$("#image_data a").fancybox(
{
'titlePosition' : 'inside',
'docid': $('#company_name').val(),
'productId' : '1234'

});
```

How i can pass productId as a current id of a tag.

```
$("#image_data a").fancybox(
{
'titlePosition' : 'inside',
'docid': $('#company_name').val(),
'productId' : $(this).attr('id')

});
```

Given code is not working,
So any other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

use one variable outside of `fancybox` and then assign the variable to `productId`

```
 var id = $(this).attr('id');  

 $("#image_data a").fancybox(
     {
       'titlePosition' : 'inside',
       'docid': $('#company_name').val(),
       'productId' : id 

  });
```